# A function is given by $f(x)=x^4−2x^3−2x^2+6x−3$. What is the solution set for $f(x)\geqslant 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A function is given by  $f(x)=x^4−2x^3−2x^2+6x−3$. What is the solution set for  $f(x)\geqslant 0$?

Comment: Hint:  this factors easily.

Comment: You'll also want to use the fact that $f$ can only change sign where $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: As f(1)=0 by the factor theorem (x-1) is a factor but I am not sure how I can work out what the rest of the roots are as well as what the graph looks like without using a graphics calculator?

Comment: @fjkl, after you factor out an $x-1$, you'll be left with a cubic. Look to see if it has any obvious roots.

Answer (score 2):

$f(1)=0$.  Trivially obvious.   Looking at the derivative $4x^3-6x^2-4x+6\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$, none other.

Note that $f'(1)=0$, making that point a double root.

See my comment below - I missed other root.

Comment: Does the derivative relate to whether f(x) is greater than or equal to 0? Even if f(1)=0 how do I find out which parts of the graph are greater than or equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$f(x) = (x^4 - 2x^2 - 3) - (2x^3 - 6x).$

$(x^2 - 3)$ is a factor in both of the above terms.

Solution

$$f(x) = (x^2 - 3) \times [(x^2 + 1) - 2x] ~=~ (x^2 - 3) \times (x - 1)^2.$$

Therefore, $f(x)$ hits the $x$-axis at $~-\sqrt{3}, ~1, ~$ and $~+\sqrt{3}.$

Since the tag is *pre-calculus*, I will complete the solution without Calculus.

To determine for which regions $f(x)$ is non-negative, explore a specific value inside of the pertinent regions.  The idea is that if a specific value inside of a region is negative, the entire region must be negative.  This follows because otherwise $f(x)$, being a continuous function, would have to hit the $x$-axis at some location other than $~-\sqrt{3}, ~1, ~$ and $~+\sqrt{3}.$

By a symmetrical argument, if a specific value inside of a region is positive, the entire region must be positive.

The exploration can be done without a calculator by employing the following shortcut:

$f(x) = (x^2 - 3) \times (x - 1)^2.$

When $x \neq 1,~$ the 2nd factor above (being the square of a number) will always be positive.  Therefore, for any value of $x$ that is not a root, the sign of $f(x)$ will be completely determined by the sign of $(x^2 - 3).$  Therefore

$$f(x) > 0 \iff (x^2 - 3) > 0.$$

Therefore

$$f(x) \geq 0 \iff x~ \text{is in one of the following regions:}$$

$$[x \leq -\sqrt{3}] ~\text{or} ~[x = 1] ~\text{or} ~[x \geq +\sqrt{3}].$$

Comment: I can pull out a 2x in the second bracket but I dont know how to factorise the quartic?

Comment: @fjkl What if you had the polynomial $(t^2 - 2t - 3)$ and you were told that one of the factors is $(t -3)$?  Could you obtain the 2nd factor?  Assuming so, just pretend that $t = x^2.$

Comment: Factor $(x^2-3)(x^2+1-2x)=(x-1)^2(x^2-3)$.  Positive roots are $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @fjkl you can intuitively do so by completing the square: $$\begin{align}&=x^{4}-2x^{2}-3\\ &=\underbrace{x^{4}-2x^{2}\color{red}{+1}}\color{red}{-1}-3\\ &= (x^{2}-1)^{2}-4 \\ &=\left(x^{2}-3\right)\left(x^{2}+1\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, I've got to f(x)=(x-1)^2(x^2-3). How do I figure out where f(x) is positive?

Comment: @fjkl see my edited answer.